# Using POST for non-modifying requests in a REST service

Tags: rest, http, service

I am puzzled about the conventions to use for implementing a REST service: as far as I understand, if the service does not change anything about the state of the server, a GET request should be used.

But if the service is expected to accept some data and to give back a result for that data, a GET request cannot be reasonable be used because it cannot have a request body (according to some pages I have read) or if it does have a request body, it should not influence the semantics of the service. What is the correct way to deal with this?

Also, what is the best strategy to return metadata about a service and in what way? For example, if the service accepts a POST request to process my data, would using GET to the same endpoint be a good convention to return metadata about the service?

UPDATE: examples for the kind of service I have in mind: send a collection of documents and get back a matrix of document similarities, send a large CSV file and get back some kind of statistical analysis .. that sort of thing. Essentially the services calculates f(x) where x tends to be a large file.

Comment: In most of these cases it turns out that the POST request is intuitively correct and _does_ actually create or modify some resource on the server, though often one not explicitly mentioned so far. A transaction for example _can_ be such a resource.

Comment: " if the service is expected to accept some data and to give back a result for that data" Could your please name an example for this? It will probably be as @arkascha wrote: There is a resource hidden inside your use case that wants to be aknowledged.

Comment: It sounds like you don’t need REST for this. An RPC-style service (via POST) may work better for you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have tried to explain better the kind of service I am talking about. The service I am talking about does not create or modify anything on the server apart maybe from some log files.